# xml file does not report error, given a reference external dtd file

Tags: xml, dtd

I have written a dtd file to regulate a xml file, but when wrote something wrong according to definition in the dtd file, I found no any errors exported by Eclipse. I reviewed many times on both files but found no mistake by myself. Below are the 2 simple files. Could anybody help to figure out what I am missing or the reason why no error reported? Thanks in advance.

Here is the dtd file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<--!no classNo or one classNo at most, at least one teacher-->
<!DOCTYPE school [
    <!ELEMENT school (class)>
    <!ELEMENT class (classNo?,teacher+)>
    <!ElEMENT classNo (#PCDATA)> 
    <!ElEMENT teacher (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

Here is the xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE school SYSTEM "Teacher.dtd">

<school>
    <class>
        <classNo>Class 3</classNo>
        <teacher>Mary</teacher>
    </class>
</school>
```

If I add another classNo Element, no error reported. The xml file and dtd file are in the same package in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DTD is ill-formed. The `DOCTYPE` declaration should only be in the XML document, not in the DTD. There are a couple of typos as well (lower-case "l" instead of upper-case "L"; `--!` in the comment should be `!--`).

The XML document validates against this DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT school (class)>
<!ELEMENT class (classNo?,teacher+)>
<!ELEMENT classNo (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT teacher (#PCDATA)>
```

You also have to make sure that validation is enabled in Eclipse of course (assuming that XML Editors and Tools is installed).

Comment: Yes, that is right. You helped me to discover 2 mistakes I had in the DTD file. One is the  DOCTYPE declaration, and the other is the comment format. Everything goes normal after amended as yours. Thanks a lot!